# Set up Azure Application Insights for local environment

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have set up **Application Insights** for our **Dev** & **Prod** environments, not with the SDK but through the Portal. We're now in the process of installing the SDK so we can have more control over customizing logging, what to measure in performance, etc.

I have found how to separate the environments in code (separate Instrumentation Key in different config files etc), but I have found nothing when it comes to my ***local environment***. Which instrumentation key should I use there, the dev one? Wouldn't then this skew our dev metrics everytime one of the developers runs the app locally?

And also, doesn't it make sense to have a **separate App Service slot** just for the local environment, so I can test everything and see the logs I'm trying out locally, and not have to deploy to dev everytime I want to see what I'm doing?

I've tried creating a separate slot for local, but it generates a weird url based on the name I give, which I can't change later.

I've googled for a couple of days already and couldn't find any (or very little) helpful advice when it comes to this.

I realise there is a "**Just add the SDK to try local only mode**" option in Visual Studio, but then I would have to use it exclusively locally. What I want is to use all three - my local, dev & prod.

We're using **.net core 2.2** for our backend and **Angular 7** for front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

The url set up automatically basically means nothing. I solved the problem by just adding another App Service slot (created from our App Service production one, just like dev), and added this key to the local settings in our project.

Now we can use this key to get real time results as we debug, and use the other two for dev & production.