# Test @microsoft/applicationinsights-web locally on angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to test application insights by Microsoft locally? All guides I have found feature testing it on the Azure portal and I can't do that since that would mean to test it on production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Asp.net core` with `angular` we have **Application Insights SDK (local)** to test Application Insights Locally in a ***Visual Studio***.

[image]

Otherwise, we need to use ***Application Insights*** connect with ***azure***.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206462/set-up-azure-application-insights-for-local-environment)